# R testthat image file not found for image snapshot

Tags: r, testthat

I am trying to use `testthat`'s `expect_snapshot_file` to test a plotting function that uses `ggplot2`. I largely copied over the example from the [vignette on snapshots](https://testthat.r-lib.org/articles/snapshotting.html), but get an error indicating that the temporary image file created for the test cannot be found.

Here is the test file's code:

```
save_png <- function(code, width = 400, height = 400) {
  path <- tempfile(fileext = ".png")
  png(path, width = width, height = height)
  on.exit(dev.off())
  code

  path
}

expect_snapshot_plot <- function(name, code) {
  name <- paste0(name, ".png")
  announce_snapshot_file(name = name)
  path <- save_png(code)
  expect_snapshot_file(path, name)
}

test_that("end to end", {
  # OMITTED: code to generate the output `out`

  name = "losses_plot"
  expect_snapshot_plot(name, plot_losses(out))
})
```

`plot_losses` is my plotting function, which uses `ggplot2`:

```
plot_losses <- function(out) {
  out %>%
    ggplot() +
    geom_point(aes(x, y, color = k))
}
```

Comment: Also, take a look at `vdiffr::expect_doppelganger()`.  See [here](https://vdiffr.r-lib.org/index.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap `code` (the plotting call) with `show`:

```
save_png <- function(code, width = 400, height = 400) {
  path <- tempfile(fileext = ".png")
  png(path, width = width, height = height)
  on.exit(dev.off())
  show(code)  # CHANGE HERE

  path
}

# Everything else the same.
```